# Amazon PHP SDK minimal files

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm working with the [Amazon SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/), which is a little over 2MB when extracted. I only need the functionality for S3.

Is it possible to extract only the required files for S3 from the SDK and use those? If so, which files do I need?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious-- What's your motivation for trying to minimize the size of the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an almost-official answer from the AWS forums:

> Hey! This is a feature we've been thinking about better supporting in the future, but right now, there is no official or supported way to do this. That said, I think you might be able to get away with keeping the following files for using only S3:
>   lib/cachecore/*
>   lib/dom/*
>   lib/requestcore/*
>   sdk.class.php
>   services/s3.class.php
>   utilities/*
>   You could also delete a few more items out of the of the utilities directory like the hadoop ones, manifest, stacktemplate, and stepconfig.
>
> I successfully made a list_buckets call with just these files, but
>   obviously you are going to want to test all of your API calls to make
>   sure that they work and that you aren't missing any dependencies that
>   I might have overlooked. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I used this dedicated class before http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class and it did the job just fine